# How to flex wrap these child elements when resized

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to wrap the child elements on smaller devices, but even when I set flex-wrap they don't move to next row. How to move them to next row when resized and stack them one by one on mobile. Please see the code pen.
https://codepen.io/Nickbing/pen/KKKdyVm

```css
.container {
  padding: 5rem;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="child">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary flex container (`.container`) has a fixed width of 1200px.

Your nested flex container (`.content`), which is set to wrap, has a width of 100%.

Because the primary container is inflexible (it will never shrink), the nested container will never shrink either (it's always 100% of 1200px), and the items never get squeezed to the next line.

Give the primary container a flexible width, and the nested container's items a minimum width, and then they'll be forced to wrap.

```css
.container {
  padding: 5rem;
  /* width: 1200px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1 0 100px; /* adjustment */
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="child">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m785c3Lp/)

Comment: `flex: 1 0 100px;` is a good approach either. Especially, stepping down when the size shrinks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I know how to get the space between flex items instead of putting margin right?

Comment: Grid is a cleaner and simpler solution. https://jsfiddle.net/w7ynghbk/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't set the `container`'s width to some value. It always set the width that value and never shrinks below that value. Do this instead:

```
body {
   width: 100vw;
} 

.container {
   padding: 5rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Then use `media queries` for mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    .content {
       flex-direction: column; 
    }

    .child {
       margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
 }
```